# Discord bot is responding to everything 3 times all of the sudden. No changes were made and no errors are shown on startup or when cmds are executed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My question is below the code.

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import requests
import json
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')
bot.remove_command("help")
 
def get_quote():
 response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
 json_data = json.loads(response.text)
 quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
 return(quote)
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
 print('The bot is online')
 await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('>help | Bot made by ColeTMK'))
 
@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):
 quote = get_quote()
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Random Quote", description=(quote), color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
 await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Clear Messages", description=f'{amount} messages were deleted!', color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await asyncio.sleep(3)
 await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
 
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 await member.ban(reason=reason)
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Ban", description=f'User {member} has been banned!', color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 await member.kick(reason=reason)
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Kick", description=f'User {member} has been kicked!', color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")
 
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Pong!", description=f'My ping is {round(bot.latency*1000)}ms', color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.command()
async def shelp(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Suici** Hotlines", description="US - 800-273-8255, Canada - 833-456-4566, Mexico - 55-5259-8121, Ireland - 116 123 OR text HELLO to 50808, Australia - 13 11 14 United Kingdom - 01708 765200. Remember that you are LOVED! You can do this, we believe in you! If you dont see your country above, please open a support ticket and we will find the # for you.", color=0x00FFFF)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.command()
async def deadchat(ctx):
 embed=discord.Embed(description="AYOOO CHAT IS DEAD! SPEAK HUMANS SPEAKKK YOU MUST!", color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=0, reason=None):
   if reason == None:
       reason = "no reason provided"
  
   if member.id == ctx.author.id:
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, AYOO you can't mute yourself!")
       return
 
   role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")
 
   if role in ctx.guild.roles:
       await member.add_roles(role)
       embed=discord.Embed(title="Temp. Mute", description=f"Offender: {member.mention} was successfully temp. muted!", color=0x00FFFF)
       embed.add_field(name="Duration", value=f'{time} seconds', inline=True)
       embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f'{reason}', inline=True)
       embed.add_field(name="Moderator", value=f'{ctx.author.name}', inline=True)
       await ctx.send(embed=embed)
       await asyncio.sleep(time)
       await member.remove_roles(role)
   else:
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Make sure your muted role is called `muted` in all lowercase! Then try again.")
 
@tempmute.error
async def tempmute_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")       
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
 
   if member.id == ctx.message.author.id: # If author
       await ctx.send("You can't mute yourself")
       return
   if member:
     role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='muted')
 
   if role in ctx.guild.roles:
       await member.add_roles(role)
       embed=discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f"Offender: {member.mention} has been muted until further notice!", color=0x00FFFF)
       embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f'{reason}', inline=True)
       embed.add_field(name="Moderator", value=f'{ctx.author.name}', inline=True)
       await ctx.send(embed=embed)
   else:
     await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Make sure your muted role is called `muted` in all lowercase! Then try again.")
 
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")
      
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} HEY YOU NUGGET! You need to tell me who you want to mute! ")
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member,):
  
   if member.id == ctx.author.id:
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, your not even muted LMAOOO")
       return   
  
   role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='muted')
   await member.remove_roles(role)
   embed=discord.Embed(title="Unmute", description=f"{member.mention} was succesfully unmuted!", color=0x00FFFF)
   embed.add_field(name="Moderator", value=f'{ctx.author.name}', inline=True)
   await ctx.send(embed=embed) 
 
@unmute.error
async def unmute_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
       await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, Sorry, you do not have permission to do that!")
 
@bot.command()
async def loved(ctx):
 embed=discord.Embed(title="Remember that you are loved! :heart: :heart: :heart:", description="Don't forget that!", color=0x00FFFF)
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, text):
 message = ctx.message
 await message.delete()
 await ctx.send(f"{text}")
 print(f"{message.author} said {text} in {message.author.guild}")
 
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
       return
   msg_content = message.content.lower()
 
   curseWord = ['bad words here']
   author = message.author.id
 
   if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
     await message.delete()
     embed=discord.Embed(title="No No Word", description=f"{message.author.mention}, Hey! Those words arent allowed here!", color=0x00FFFF)
     await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
     print(f"{message.author.name} said {message.content} in {message.author.guild}")
   else:
     await bot.process_commands(message)
 
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content.startswith(">numbergame"):
       channel = message.channel
       await channel.send("Guess the number from 0-100 by writing the number in this channel!")
 
       number = random.randint(1,100)
 
       def check(m):
           return m.content.isdigit() and m.channel == channel and m.author == message.author
 
       print(number)
  
       while True:
           try:
               msg = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
           except asyncio.TimeoutError:
               return await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, You are late to guess!")
           guess = int(msg.content)
           if guess == number:
               return await channel.send(f"Correct answer! {message.author.mention}")
           elif guess > number:
               await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, Your guess was too high!")
           elif guess < number:
               await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, Your guess was too low!")
   else:
       await bot.process_commands(message)
 
keep_alive()
 
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Starting a few minutes ago, everytime i do a command, it prints it 3 times instead of just once like its always been doing. There are no commands that are pasted twice or anything like that. MY QUESTION is, is there anything in the code that makes the bot to do it? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the bot? Also, try to provide an MRE instead of your entire code.

Comment: @Ceres I'm running it on Repl.it

Comment: Put the code into your question, not as a link. Or put it on GitHub. You may be running the bot multiple times.

Comment: @Ceres It's edited for you.

Comment: if you don't stop/kill bot then it may still run - and if you run bot again then system will run two bots at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem already append to me and don't worry, your code is not the problem. Sometimes, your bot can still running when you close your program, then when you relaunch your code there are two launched codes on the bot account etc... To fix it, regenerate the token on your bot page and don't forget to update your code in consequence.